# go mod tidy: "no matching versions for query "latest""

Tags: go, go-modules

go version

```
go version go1.19.4 linux/amd64
```

go env

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ishmeets/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/ishmeets/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS="-modcacherw"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/ishmeets/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY="xxx"
GONOSUMDB="xxx"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ishmeets/go"
GOPRIVATE="xxx"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/home/ishmeets/.local"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/ishmeets/.local/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.19.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/ishmeets/go/pkg/mod/xxx/xxx/fabric-mgmt-api@v0.0.0-20230119053658-acd5a1e86128/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build2990676511=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

When I do `go mod tidy` in the module cache, it's giving this error.

```
xxx/xxx/fabric-mgmt-api/internal/app/network-mgmt/xxx/primitives/mock: no matching versions for query "latest"
```

I have placed the mock files at location that is having the package mock. Still, error is there.

Things I have tried.

1. Copy the repo outside GOMODCACHE. Then `go mod tidy` works.
   `cp -a ~/go/pkg/mod/xxx/xxx/fabric-mgmt-api@v0.0.0-20230119053658-acd5a1e86128 ~/workspace/`
   `cd ~/workspace/fabric-mgmt-api@v0.0.0-20230119053658-acd5a1e86128 && go mod tidy`
2. Used go 1.18. This also works.
3. Tried on go 1.20.1. It doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to run `go mod tidy` in the module cache at all? You should not be manipulating any files in the module cache, if they are modified or corrupt the `go` tool is not going to work correctly.

Comment: @JimB I am adding a few mock files in a private repo in module cache. It is an in house created repo. `go mod tidy` in module cache used to work in go 1.18.

Comment: It's not meant to work that way, so misusing it is not guaranteed to continue working in new releases. If you want to modify a dependency, use `replace` or go workspaces.

Comment: @JimB Is there some patch feature in `go mod tidy` or `go get` that can do apply changes in the repo after it downloads in mod cache.

Comment: No, `go mod tidy` inspects dependencies and updates `go.mod` and `go.sum`. If you want to modify a dependency you need to do that externally then use `replace`.